# PHP Dynamic page css bug

Tags: php, html, css

i have a dynamic php web page

```
localhost/ctd/index.php
```

All working good except if i add a forward slash to it like below:

```
localhost/ctd/index.php/
```

the css doesnt load..

is this a css bug or PHP?

**The full code of index.php**

```
<?php
define('pageaccess', TRUE); 
$action = $_GET['p'];
include "views/header.php";
if($action=='student')
{
    include "views/student.php";
}else if($action=='college'){       
    include "views/college.php";
}else if($action==''){      
    include "views/home.php";
}else{
    include "views/404.php";
}   
include "views/footer.php";
?>
```

**CSS link**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ctdu_style.css" />
```

Point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I have seen this kind of issue in so many php enabled web applications. 

I believe we have a fix for it.

Comment: This is most likely caused by relative path issues in the CSS includes, but we cannot know for sure without seeing your code. Can you post the relevant snippets?

Comment: If you use a relative path for your css, it should search that files in the directory "localhost/ctd/index.php/". I think that directory not exists ;) You can use Tamper Data for showing which files were loaded (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) Otherwise use absolute paths for your css!

Comment: Show your `<link>` tag that loads the css, and check your server's access/error logs to see if the css file is being requested at all, and what the requested url is if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your link is relative.

For example, if you have link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
```

And you're currently at `http://localhost/example.php/` then it loads `http://localhost/example.php/css.css`. It's server-specific thing, some servers implement this "feature", some not. The browser thinks it's directory, while in fact it isn't. Some PHP scripts use this behavior, for example MediaWiki uses `index.php` as directory to emulate `.htaccess` when server doesn't support `.htaccess` files, but supports CGI scripts as directories.

The solution would be either making sure that every path uses page root instead of current directory (for example `/css.css` instead of `css.css`).

Second solution would be sort of hacky, but would convert links. Don't use if you actually want to use this sort of links (but I doubt this :P).

```
<?php
$request_uri = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ($request_uri !== $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue myself a while ago, but my issue was more the fact I was using .htaccess to rewrite urls and when a `/` was added at the end of a url it caused the css and other included files to return a 404 Not found error.

The reason is that if you have a `/` at the end it will interpret `index.php` as being a directory rather than a file.

The fix that worked for me and may work for you too is to prefix all of your included files with a `/` for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ctdu_style.css" />
```

would become

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ctdu_style.css" />
```